# Countable-dimensional normed spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Can you give me an example of a countable-dimensional normed space? 
I don't find anyone

Comment: Depends what you mean by countable-dimension, in the Hamel or Schauder sense. It's worth noting that that Banach spaces cannot have countably infinite Hamel dimension.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you are talking about Hamel dimension.

Take any  infinite dimensional normed linear space $Y$ and take a sequence $(x_n)$ of linearly independent vectors in it. Then $X=span (x_1,x_2,...)$ is a countable dimensional normed linear space.

Specific example: the space of all finitely non-zero sequences with the norm from $\ell^{2}$ is one such space.

Polynomials on $[0,1]$ with the sup norm is another example.